# How to extract the latest rows

Tags: sql, db2, ibm-midrange

I have a table like this:

```
Table A
Date    Time    ID  Ref
110217  91703   A001    A1100056
110217  91703   A001    A1100057
110217  91703   A001    A1100058
110217  91703   A001    A1100059
110217  132440  A001    A1100057
110217  132440  A001    A1100058
110217  132440  A001    A1100060
110217  91703   B001    B1100048
110217  91703   B001    B1100049
110217  132440  B001    B1100049
110217  132440  B001    B1100050
```

I wish to have the latest data only & the final result should look like this using SQL:

```
Date    Time    ID  Ref
110217  132440  A001    A1100057
110217  132440  A001    A1100058
110217  132440  A001    A1100060
110217  132440  B001    B1100049
110217  132440  B001    B1100050
```

*(3 records all with the same "latest" time)*

The database will self-update by itself at certain time. The problem is: I do not know the exact time, hence I do not know which record is the latest.

Comment: Which latest row are you looking for?  The example returns all rows, just replacing the time with the latest time.

Comment: How do you get the second result from the first one? You have invented new rows. Or changed data or something...

Comment: What **database** and version are you using?? These things are beyond the standardized SQL - they're often vendor-specific extensions...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works in SQL Server:

```
SELECT TOP 1 WITH TIES *
FROM TableA
ORDER BY Date DESC, Time DESC
```

And this solution is probably server-independent:

```
SELECT a.*
  FROM TableA a
  JOIN (
       SELECT d.MaxDate, MAX(t.Time) AS MaxTime
         FROM TableA t
         JOIN (
              SELECT MAX(Date) AS MaxDate
                FROM TableA
              ) d
           ON t.Date = d.MaxDate
        GROUP BY d.MaxDate
       ) m
    ON a.Date = m.MaxDate AND a.Time = m.MaxTime
```

Comment: Error: SQL0104 - Token 1 was not valid. Valid tokens: + - AS <IDENTIFIER>. (State:37000, Native Code: FFFFFF98). I'm using DB2/400 SQL

Comment: @Bob: Posted an alternative solution.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY date DESC, time DESC LIMIT 1;
```

Will give you the latest row in MySql.

Comment: Error: SQL0104 - Token LIMIT was not valid. Valid tokens: <END-OF-STATEMENT>. (State:37000, Native Code: FFFFFF98). I'm using DB2/400 SQL

Comment: I apologise for that, the poster did not specify the type of database.

Answer (score 0):

Which database are you using? You can actually concat the two columns after converting them to a date and time format, and then order by date. All this can be achieved in query.

Comment: before doing the above you need convert them to integer for valid sorting if their data type varchar.  SELECT

Comment: how can I do the concat the two columns in query ?

Comment: You can use Concat(str1,str2), these functions can be part of conditions and order by clause. It would be like SELECT * FROM table order by Concat(str1,str2); i assume str1 - is formated to date and st2 to time using date functions.